# image field not found

Tags: php

It doesnt see image if I upload. Image input name="projects[]".

I want move file to path but it doesnt see file in my PHP.

My code:

```
    public function processProject()
    {

        if (!empty($_FILES['projects']['name']) and empty(Message::$msgs)) {
            $upl = Upload::instance(3145728, "png,jpg");
            $upl->process("projects", UPLOADS . '/' . $safe->category . '/', "MEM_");
        }



            if (!empty($_FILES['projects']['name'])) {
                $data['cover'] = $upl->fileInfo['fname'];
            }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflown . Please clarify your question by showing **only the relevant code parts**, I can't see the insert SQL in your question so you need to include referenced class functions as well as Database structure information (column attributes) and sample data that causes the problem and an illustration of what outcome you're expecting. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Thanks.

Comment: @Martin I have two different insert statements and second statement doesnt work. If category doesnt exist then it runs category insert statement and then should also run project insert statement.

Comment: Where is the value `$safe->category` set?

Comment: So is it category insert or project insert that doesn't work? I was reading that the second category insert was faulty? Please clarify. Thanks .

Comment: @Martin from rules and rules coming from inputs name="category"

Comment: Project insert doesnt work.

Comment: if you can **edit and update your question** to show this, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @Martin updated

Comment: [read the PHP manual about multiple file uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php)